# Latest update of Apple iPhone 6s version 9.3.2 will not let me use most of my apps

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting a "network error" code, no matter which Wi-Fi I am using.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try resetting your network settings. Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.

Comment: I deleted two apps that wouldn't work, I reset the network setting as stated.  I powered down my iphone and then restarted it after 10 min.  I searched and re-installed the apps.  Still getting error message "network error" on the nest app.  and "network is not available." for starbucks app.  Although, I can get into Facebook.   Any optional ideas?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your Network Settings:

Settings > General > Reset and click "Reset Network Settings"

Comment: I deleted two apps that wouldn't work, I reset the network setting as stated.  I powered down my iphone and then restarted it after 10 min.  I searched and re-installed the apps.  Still getting error message "network error" on the nest app.  and "network is not available." for starbucks app.  Although, I can get into Facebook.   Any optional ideas?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @debbie maybe you could restore your phone to an older backup? I can't really think of anything else to do